# I need to run query in Automation through soap api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, query, automation

I need to run query in Automation through soap api its Automation creating  but Activity not Created when i click on that its showing Error like automation no longer exists this is my code

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>testuser@sfdc.com</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>xxxxxxxx</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client>
               <ID>7208433</ID>
            </Client>
            <Name>myautos</Name>
            <CustomerKey>7567544333</CustomerKey>
            <AutomationTasks>
               <AutomationTask>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Activities>
                     <Activity>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <Name>Query</Name><!-- Name of Activity -->
                        <CustomerKey>5467777</CustomerKey>
                        <!--<Definition>
                           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                        </Definition>-->
                        <ActivityObject xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                           <CustomerKey>5467777</CustomerKey><!-- CustomerKey of Query -->
                           <Name>joinmultiple</Name><!-- Name of Query -->
                        </ActivityObject>
                     </Activity>
                  </Activities>
               </AutomationTask>
            </AutomationTasks>
            <AutomationType>Scheduled</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform Query Activity, you need to retrieve the ObjectID of the QueryDefinition first.

Check this Answer: [Create and Perform a query with PHP SOAP API in ExactTarget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205262/create-and-perform-a-query-with-php-soap-api-in-exacttarget/205280#205280)